# pegar valor da célula de excel abaixo ou ao lado depois de verificar o nome do campo

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

boas.
tenho uma arquivo de excel que apresenta informação informação abaixo.
eu pretendo extrair alguma informação e montar uma tabela única com as seguintes colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o arquivo original, ele quebra a informação a cada 11 linhas... a ideia seria verificar o nome do campo e selecionar a informação na celula ao lado ou abaixo consoante a posição da informação e mudar para a linha de baixo da nova tabela.
tem como fazer ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Sugiro gravar uma macro fazendo o que deseja com o primeio bloco de dados. A partir daí, poderia fazer um loop, para pesquisar pelo termo "Definitiva", e rodar novamente sua macro. Claro que terá que adaptar ai aos dados, mas se tentar poste o código aqui e terá mais chances de receber ajuda da comunidade.

Comment: obrigado @Evert, já estou a fazer isso mesmo... :)

Comment: Olá @Pedro, como está indo? Algum avanço? Conseguiu alcançar o desejado?